# PostgreSQL Query tuning up

Tags: postgresql

I am looking to tune up my query.

```sql
SELECT student_id,net_id
FROM nstudent
WHERE status_id=3
INNER JOIN ndepart using (net_id)
WHERE NOT deleted;
```

The above query shows the result but i also want to get the depart_name which is ndepart table, but i cannot figure out how would i do it (probably in descending order)?

Types

- student_id,net_id are bigint.
- depart_name is character
- status_id is integer.

FK/PK's

- net_id is primary key for ndepart
- foreign key in nstudent and student_id is primary key for nstudent.

Thank you

Comment: Do not create multiple copies of same question. The previous question had comments about the improvement you needed to do to get an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple PostgresSQL queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425710/multiple-postgressql-queries)

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT S.student_id, S.net_id, D.depart_name
FROM nstudent S
INNER JOIN ndepart D ON S.net_id = D.net_id 
WHERE s.status_id = 3
AND NOT d.deleted;
```